# Play Sound when rotation is (0,0,0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a pendulum in my game and try to play a sound when the rotation of the pendulum is (0,0,0) & Time.timeScale!=0 .The script works fine but if i increase the rotation speed of the pendulum the sound stops playing or is skipped multiple time(If in **TimeManager** I set **time scale** to **0.1** the sound clip is played).

**Pendulum Code**

```
Quaternion qStart, qEnd;
float angle = 20.0f;
public float speed;
Public AudioSource Sound;

void Start () {

    qStart = Quaternion.AngleAxis ( angle, Vector3.forward);
    qEnd   = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-angle, Vector3.forward);
}

void Update () {
        //rotation code
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (qStart, qEnd, (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) + 1.0f) / 2.0f);

        //Playing Sound
        if (transform.rotation == Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0) && Time.timeScale!=0)
            Sound.Play ();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a real pendulum is in continuous, smooth motion, but your simulated pendulum moves in discrete time slices with each Unity update frame, unless the time slices are very small (and they get bigger as timeScale increases) your rotation will skip from a positive angle position to negative angle (and vice versa) without reaching exactly 0; the trick then is to detect the transitional frame and play the sound then. Given that the mid-point occurs when your Lerp factor is 0.5, you can simplify the check to be "for the current Lerp factor and the previous, if one greater than or equal to 0.5 and the other isn't":

```
Quaternion qStart, qEnd;
float angle = 20.0f;
float previousLerpFactor;

public float speed;
public AudioSource Sound;

void Start () {

    qStart = Quaternion.AngleAxis ( angle, Vector3.forward);
    qEnd   = Quaternion.AngleAxis (-angle, Vector3.forward);
}

void Update () {
        //Lerp factor
        float lerpFactor = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;

        //rotation code
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (qStart, qEnd, lerpFactor);

        //Playing Sound
        if (((lerpFactor >= 0.5f) ^ (previousLerpFactor >= 0.5f)) && Time.timeScale!=0)
            Sound.Play ();

        previousLerpFactor = lerpFactor;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what is happening is that the rotation is going straight from positive to negative, or vice versa, without ever hitting (0,0,0) in between. If the angle is -0.1 at one moment and 0.1 at the next, it will never equal 0 and your sound will never play.

Instead of testing whether or not `transform.rotation` is (0,0,0), try watching when `Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed)` goes from positive to negative or vice versa.